# Webpack with less to theme the page with colorpicker values

Tags: less, themes, webpack

I am trying to implement themeing on 'webpack' project using less. Where the page already has a default them and the user is given a pop up to select different colors with color picker and once it selects any the theme changes entirely for the website or the sample page.

Does anyone have any idea about how i can go about this.  Any sample git hub project where i can refer this process as a base project. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Please Note i have already set up the project with the web.config. and less loader , i am confused on to sort how i can go about with the call to less and themeing option.

Can anyone suggest!

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I think you can use lessjs to dynamically compile less files. 
https://github.com/less/less.js/

Comment: Can you please eleborate on the usage of this less. How i can fit it with webpack and colorpicker option